# jQuery UI - links w/i tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want make sure that any link I click inside a given tab, actually calls that url INTO the tab... the docs say I can do this, but there are a few posts here that show I'm not the only one who is running into an issue... I have tried the code from the jQuery UI site, and I've tried the suggestions in other articles on this site... I'm sure it's an OBVIOUS problem to someone firmiliar with JS and jQuery... please help....

here's where I'm @ so far....(each 'trial' should be done w/o the other code on th epag - its just here so you have the code I've tried, and maybe can see commonality )

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

// trial #1 - specific ID called into tab - doesn't work
$('#tabs-community').tabs('select', 'tabs-signup');

  $('#blogs').click(function() {
      $('#tabs-bboard').load('blogs.cfm');
 });      

// trial #2 - the documented way - doesn't work
$('#tabs-community').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
    $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
        $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
    return false;
    });
}
});

// trial #3 - suggestion given on this site - doesn't work
$('#tabs-community').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
    $('a', ui.panel).live('click', function() {
        $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
    return false;
    });
}
});

});

</script>       
<article class="col1">
    <div id="tabs-community" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-bboard">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-signup">Sign-up</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-bboard">
            <cfinclude template="bboard.php"><br/>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-signup">
            <cfinclude template="signup_form.php"><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

The "bboard.php" looks like this

```
<a href="blogs1.cfm" id="blogs">blogs 1</a>
<a href="blogs2.cfm" >blogs 2</a>
<a href="blogs3.cfm" >blogs 3</a>
```

All links ALWAYS open as a fresh page call... NONE of the examplse load the link INTO the tab...

thank you for any assistance.

Comment: what code on UI site, none of demos have links in content?

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach for creating tabs that load in external content looks like this.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/foo.php">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bar.php">bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In your case instead of pointing the `href` of the anchor tags at divs, point them at the URL where the content is located.

Comment: @chrisvillanueva The panels will be created automatically for you when the XHRs to retrieve content complete.

Answer (score 0):

OK... figured out the issue and it is a simple one. When page loads and tabs are created there is no load event triggered. All of your click handlers are buried in the load callback of tabs and never get bound to any of the initial links in tabs content. Thus the initial links all load a new page.

Solution is to take the click handler out of load callback. If using jquery > 1.7 `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/c7arQ/

Demo ses slightly different ajax due to contraints of jsfiddle

```
$(function() {

    /* delegate click handler to id=tabs to account for future elements */         
    $('#tabs').on('click', '.ui-tabs-panel a', function(){
        /* get parent tab panel to load into */                                             
        var $panel=$(this).closest('.ui-tabs-panel');
        $panel.load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('#tabs').tabs();​

});
```

EDIT: remove your $('#blogs')  click handler to avoid duplicate loading

Comment: Charlie - I really wanted that to work - but no go...
yes it works in jsFiddle... but not for me...
here is a demo http://207.179.103.233/tabs_links_test.htm

Comment: 2 things. Look in console and will see script error on page load. There is some non printing bad character pasted into file. Wrap code in `$(function()` also

Comment: FYI- running the click handler in console makes it work fine on your page... the ajax is loading properly